# What is the proper pronunciation of "kitten?"

Tags: pronunciation

The American Heritage Dictionary says 'KIT-n' but speakers in my locale (west coast US) say 'Ki with short i, glottal stop, n.' There is no 't' sound. Do we speak slang, a dialect, or are we pronouncing it correctly?

The only reference I found here was from last May:
"Intervocalic /t/ almost always reduces to a single flap [ɾ] there. That’s why ladder and latter are homophonic, although kitten and kiddin’ are not. Indeed, kitten may become just [ˈkʰɪʔn̩] (sometimes written [ˈkʰɪʔən]) , often enough."

I don't understand IPA code. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I pronounced the "tt" - turns out, like you, I don't. (US Midwest native)

Comment: When concerned with 'correctness', it's necessary to understand IPA or one of the other pronunciation systems.

Comment: The IPA means glottal stop, followed by a syllabic 'n'. You are pronouncing it the way most Americans pronounce it (certainly a large fraction of them). But I suspect this pronunciation would be considered non-standard in the U.K.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I've always had the impression glottal stops are more prevalent in British than American speech (even some of our newsreaders have started using them in recent years). Americans often avoid the extra effort of enunciating **t** by switching it to **d**, but that's quite unusual in BrE, so our standard "lazy speech" patterns include more opportunities for gloʔəl stops.

Comment: It's more complicated than a dictionary may know. My adult daughter pronounces a t sound in kitten most of the time, but when she is baby-talking to the cat she says ki-en with a very exaggerated glottal stop. She'll flap on kitty, saying kiddy, but not kidden. Complicated.

Comment: Suppose they are singing ... *Raindrops on roses and whiskers on kittens*.  Would they pronounce the T then?

Comment: @PeterShor: Brits in my hearing make two syllables of kit-ten and I hear both T's.

Comment: @GEdgar: You asked: *do Americans pronounce the 't' when singing?* [No](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPncuS0E1yc). (At least not all of them.)

Comment: @Wet You hear _both_ t’s? That is an absolute impossibility. There is no native English speaker alive who pronounces _kitten_ with two separate t’s. Phonetically double t’s can occur in extra-careful speech in words such as _hat trick_, but even there, they're nearly always merged into one, geminate, t sound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to clarify, **slang** describes a certain kind of vocabulary, and has nothing to do with pronunciation. Differences in pronunciation can be described in terms of **accent**. **Dialect** may describe differences in accent, but it is predominantly concerned with differences in vocabulary and grammatical structures.

In British English, the formal  pronunciation of *kitten* is /ˈkɪt(ə)n/. It rhymes with *Britain*, and probably does so in American English as well, because, if both are pronounced differently from the British way, I imagine they do so consistently. Some regional accents replace the ‘t’ sound, both in *kitten* and elsewhere, with a glottal stop. In fact, most speakers will do so in certain phonetic environments. There’s nothing ‘incorrect’ about doing so.

Comment: Most Americans pronounce all words ending with a Vtən (V being any vowel) in this way, but I believe it only happens with Vtən and not with any other final consonant.

Comment: Though the difference is slight, most Americans use the dental flap rather than the glottal stop for what is historically an intermedial 't'. 'rhotic', 'votive', 'writer', 'bottle', 'rotten', 'cutting' (note the more common words with syllabic nasals and liquids).

Comment: @Mitch: many Americans (I'll take back "most" after listening to forvo—it was somewhere around half of them) use the dental flap for all these words ***except*** when a 't' is followed by an 'n', in which case they use glottal stop. So for *kitten, rotten, button, eaten,* and so forth.

Comment: It's an alveolar flap, not a dental flap.

Answer (score 2):

I grew up in the tri-state area (NJ/NY/CT), CT specifically, and never realized I pronounced kitten differently until someone pointed it out. Also, mitten, smitten, etc. Primarily, we drop the tt's so it is ki'en, mi'en, etc.

Answer (score -5):

Proper pronunciation of the word Kitten, is 'kitten' not Ki'en and certainly not kit-ten.  The double T is not pronounced as two separate T's, nor is it ignored and left out altogether.  Regardless of what people think, there are not two correct ways to pronounce such a word.  Regionally, sometimes people get in a bad habit, or simple laziness comes in to play. But there is only one correct pronunciation of words like kitten or rotten etc.

Comment: If you pronounce all t's as [t]'s in American English, you sound like a foreigner, albeit one who speaks English really well.