# The origins of the North American glottalised stop in place of certain consonant groups

Tags: pronunciation

In some North American speech (not sure about Canada;), I have long noted the pronunciation of certain consonant combinations that seem to have drifted to what sounds like some form of ***glottalised stop***. The most common example is in the second syllable of the word ***'didn't ': the second 'd' sound*** to my ears is not the classical 'd' standardly spoken of English speakers, native or non-; it comes out as ***'di'n't'***.  What the hay???

As far as I can tell, it is not obviously regionalised to any particular geographical area, socio-economic sector or ethnic background. That is, it seems to be pretty pervasive across the States. (Hawaii I don't know about; I'm always busy at the luau).

I am very interested to note that Blacks and Hispanics are as likely to use it as N. Americans of European descent. That may be because I have not paid enough attention, or that these afford larger sample groups by far and swamp out the rest.

The literature - that includes disclosures/reports by non-academic speaker/users  and cross-generational accounts - surprisingly, contains lots of references to such changes right across the globe, including the States but none seem to touch on this particular glottalisation. What's the haps?

Comment: I use a glottal stop in *kitten* (where I think its use is truly widespread in the U.S.) but not *didn't.* I believe there's lots of literature on the glottal stop in AmE in words like *kitten, cotton, button, satin.* Would that do, or are you asking specifically about the one in *didn't* (which I would guess is a rarer instance of essentially the same phenomenon)?

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have waited for some time before moving beyond the possibility that it may just normal statistical variation. But it is quite distinct and widespread and I can detect no unifying pattern. Even careful Brit speakers will tend to shorten the middle 't/tt' in your list of words in the direction of gl-isation so that I chalk up to normal lenition. One of my native languages has g/stops (!) so I am pretty attuned to them. Further, in learning English, my fellow countryfolk do not carry over the g/s. I also cite 'didn't' as an example because it's an unsual candidate for g/s'ing.

Comment: See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105011/what-is-the-proper-pronunciation-of-kitten).

Comment: Peter. Again with a thank you. I shall fine tooth comb my way through those responses and see how my hair is parted on the other side. And I shall keep my ears peeled for more occurrences, mainly on everymantv

Comment: BTW, it's _glottal stop_ for the IPA symbol [ʔ]. English doesn't have any glottalized stops, which are co-articulations like [č’] or [ƛ’], as in _č’ƛ’a_, the Lushootseed word for 'rock'