# Absence of hard "t"

Tags: dialects

What dialect is this: omitting a hard "t" in a word such as button. Sounds like they're saying buh en.

Comment: Well, mine, for one. And most other people I know. At best we say *buddon*. Who *actually* says *button*? Maybe some really crisp Brits?

Comment: It's all over the map.

Comment: See [What is the proper pronunciation of “kitten?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105011)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [glottal replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization#Glottal_replacement). It happens in several dialects. According to Wikipedia:

> In RP, and in many accents such as Cockney as well as all American English, it is common for /t/ to be completely replaced by a glottal stop before another consonant, as in not now [nɒʔnaʊ] and department [dɪpʰɑː(ɹ)ʔmən̩t]. In General American (GA) English, this replacement also happens before a syllabic /n/, as in button (representable as [ˈbʌʔn̩] or [ˈbʌʔɪ̈n]).

[This page](http://davidbrett.uniss.it/phonology/glottalStop/glottalStop.html) has good examples in a British accent.